# django saving two model on a oneto many relationship

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template that I use to save two models on a one to many relationship. In this template, I have two questions the first question has radio choices and the second question has checkbox choices like what is shown on the image below. What happens is when I select, for instance, choice#1 in question 1 and check checkbox#1 in question 2 the form is saved successfully. But if I select choice#3 in question 1 and check checkbox#1 or checkbox#2 in question 2 then i get an error: CheckChoice matching query does not exist. I am not sure why i am getting this error.

```python
class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    archive = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enter_question = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.enter_question


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CheckChoice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_check = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class SurveyAnswer(models.Model):
    orig_survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_answer = models.ForeignKey(CheckChoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    survey_answer = models.ForeignKey(SurveyAnswer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```python
def survey_fill(request):
    ans = SurveyAnswer()
    orig_survey = Survey.objects.get(id=request.POST['survey_id'])
    ans.orig_survey = orig_survey
    ans.save()
    questions = orig_survey.question_set.all()
    for question in questions:
        qc = request.POST['question' + str(question.id)]
        qa = QuestionAnswer()
        qa.answer = Choice.objects.get(id=int(qc))
        qa.check_answer = CheckChoice.objects.get(id=int(qc))
        qa.survey_answer = ans
        qa.save()
    ans.save()
    return render(request, 'survey-complete.html', {})
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <form method = "post" action ="{% url 'fill-survey' %}">

    <input type = "hidden" name = "survey_id" value = {{survey.id}}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in questions %}


                <div class="p-2">
                    <h4 class="header">
                    Question {{ forloop.counter }}: {{ question.enter_question }}
                </h4>
                </div>

        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all%}


             <div class="p-2">
            <input type="radio" name ="question{{question.id}}" value={{choice.id}}>
                {{choice.choice}}
             </div>

            {% endfor %}


                {% for choice in question.checkchoice_set.all%}
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name ="question{{question.id}}" value={{choice.id}}>
                        {{choice.choice_check}}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}


        <div class="p-2">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Complete!" class = "btn btn-lg btn-success">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Updated view and template

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <form method = "post" action ="{% url 'fill-survey' %}">

    <input type = "hidden" name = "survey_id" value = {{survey.id}}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in questions %}


                <div class="p-2">
                    <h4 class="header">
                    Question {{ forloop.counter }}: {{ question.enter_question }}
                </h4>
                </div>

        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all%}


             <div class="p-2">
            <input type="radio" name ="question{{question.id}}" value={{choice.id}}>
                {{choice.choice}}
             </div>

            {% endfor %}


                {% for choice in question.checkchoice_set.all%}
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name ="checkbox{{question.id}}" value={{choice.id}}>
                        {{choice.choice_check}}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}


        <div class="p-2">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Complete!" class = "btn btn-lg btn-success">
        </div>
    </form>
```

```html
def survey_fill(request):
    ans = SurveyAnswer()
    orig_survey = Survey.objects.get(id=request.POST['survey_id'])
    ans.orig_survey = orig_survey
    ans.save()
    questions = orig_survey.question_set.all()
    for question in questions:
        if 'question' and 'checkbox' in request.POST:
            qc = request.POST['question' + str(question.id)]
            check = request.POST['checkbox' + str(question.id)]
            qa = QuestionAnswer()
            # qa1 = QuestionAnswer()
            qa.answer = Choice.objects.get(id=int(qc))
            qa.check_answer = CheckChoice.objects.get(id=int(check))
            qa.survey_answer = ans
            qa.save()
            # qa1.survey_answer = ans
            # qa1.save()

    ans.save()
    return render(request, 'survey-complete.html', {})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the checkbox element.

Your first mistake was set up the same name for all of them. They must have a different name.

You have to understand that the corresponding parameter of a checkbox is only submitted when it's checked.

A checkbox element is like a flag. When it's checked then it's on (and WILL BE submitted). But when it's not checked, then it's off (and WILL NOT BE submitted).

I think that in the server side you probably is receiving a value that is not a valid id (integer), and then you get the "matching query does not exist" error.

Comment: I've updated the view and template and change the checkbox name. Now I did not get any error, however, the data is not saved.